# Depth bias issue in directx

Tags: c++, directx, msdn

I am facing problem in directx 9 depth bias.
I have followed this link :https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/alternatives-to-using-z-bias-to-fix-z-fighting-issues

it has resolved my basic problem but the real issue comes when i move my object to edges of view port or closer to near clip depth bias fails.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem you're having? It is a z fighting issue? Right now we don't know what you're trying to fix.

Comment: Yes, it is z-fighting issue. Actually: i have 2d object in front of camera and it has its outline. I want that outline to be rendered behind object. so that overlapping part of outline is not visible.  if ( fCamDist < 510 && fCamDist>100)
    {
     _DepthBias = 0.0003f;
     _SlopeScaleDepthBias = 3.2f;
    }
    else if (fCamDist <= 100 && fCamDist > 35)
    {
     _DepthBias = 0.003f;
     _SlopeScaleDepthBias = 22.0f;
    }
    else if (fCamDist <= 35)
    {
     _DepthBias = 0.09f;
     _SlopeScaleDepthBias = 35.0f;
    }

Comment: is it my value of depth bias or angle between camera and object that makes depth-bias fails.

Comment: I am using this command:m_spd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SLOPESCALEDEPTHBIAS, dwordBitsFrom(_SlopeScaleDepthBias));
    m_spd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DEPTHBIAS, dwordBitsFrom(_DepthBias));

Answer (score 0):

@PeteBlackerThe3rd
Here are some snapshots of my issue:
1st 
How normally my 2d object withoutline looks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa8DO.jpg)
2nd 
When I apply depth bias at (0,0,0) with respect to camera.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEWZL.jpg)
3rd 
when I translate object in view port in Z and X axis. Depth bias fails.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoieF.png)